# How to automatically load previous form selections into itself and make one query for all selected types?

Tags: php, html, forms

On my website I have a search-bar. It works as a form that submits and searches my database for the value inputted in the text bar, in the column where the type is selected. My form looks like this

```
<form action=" " method="POST" >
 <select name="search_type">
<option value="fullname">People</option>
<option value="username" >Username</option>
<option value="firstname”>First Name</option>
<option value="lastname" >Last Name</option>
<option value="email" >Email</option>
</select><input type="text" name="value" >
<input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

After every search it refreshes and users have to reselect data and put it back in… is there a way to have the last item searched be reselected?
Then from that form I use PHP to check what type was selected and look at my database… Currently I have a bunch of conditionals which I feel is too inefficient, is there a way to get rid of all those conditionals and directly search specific columns in my databases from one call? (For the record my db column names are user_fullname, user_username, user_firstname, user_lastname, and user_email). 
My PHP script looks like this (I have one block conditional for each type variable)

```
If($_POST[‘search_type’] == ‘fullname’){
$results ="SELECT `user_id`, `user_username`, `user_firstname`, `user_lastname` FROM `mytable` WHERE user_fullname = {$_POST[‘value’]}";
while($results_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)){
$returned_results[] = array( ///returning stuff///);
}}
///etc
```

I have been looking for hours trying to find a way to only run one query for any type but I could have not got anything to work. Please any advice or help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: By 'automatically' do you mean you want to use AJAX to reload your form data or are you fine with the page fully reloading?

Comment: I am fine if the page reloads, by automatic I just mean when the pages loads can the information be put back in without the user having to click or type anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the conditionals in your mysql query I think the simplest method would be to just set the values of your search type to your actual column names so then you can just run your query for that value. For example your option values would be “user_fullname”,”user_username” etc in your form and for your PHP script you could try this:

```
$where = " {$_POST['search_type']} LIKE '%{$_POST[‘value’]}%'";
$results ="SELECT `user_id`, `user_username`, `user_firstname`, `user_lastname` FROM `mytable` WHERE $where";
```

I think the easiest method for you to refresh your form data and pre-select fields would be some PHP conditionals:

```
<form action="search.php" method="POST" >
 <select name="search_type">
<option value="user_fullname"<?php if($_POST['search_type'] == 'user_fullname'){echo 'selected';} ?>>People</option>
<option value="user_username" <?php if($_POST ['search_type'] == 'user_username'){echo 'selected';} ?>>Username</option>
<option value="user_firstname" <?php if($_POST ['search_type'] == 'user_firstname'){echo 'selected';} ?>>First Name</option>
<option value="user_lastname" <?php if($_POST ['search_type'] == 'user_lastname'){echo 'selected';} ?>>Last Name</option>
<option value="user_email" <?php if($_POST ['search_type'] == 'user_email'){echo 'selected';} ?>>Email</option>
</select><input type="text" name="value" value="<?php echo $_POST['email']; ?>">
<input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Comment: One question, I see you putting where in the query but what do the % in %{$_POST[‘value’]}% mean?

Comment: The % means that you can have anything on any-side of the variable. for example if you search 'jo' in your form you could get results for 'joe', 'banjo', or 'pajon'. It doesn't matter what is on the left or right if any query column value contains something similar to your search value it will be returned.

Comment: Oh alright that is cool. I guess that is probably even more helpful that just searching exactly what someone is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

To add onto Devon's answer I figured out how to combine the other conditional functions within that main call for stuff like email verification.

```
if($_POST['value'] != ''){
if($_POST['search_type'] == 'user_email'){
if(!filter_var($_POST['value'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
    { 
        die("Invalid E-Mail Address"); 
    } 
}
$where = " {$_POST['search_type']} LIKE '%{$_POST[‘value’]}%'";
$results ="SELECT `user_id`, `user_username`, `user_firstname`, `user_lastname` FROM `mytable` WHERE $where";

}
```